# Account kit SMS verification is returning "NOT_AUTHENTICATED" response status on my web page

Tags: facebook, account-kit

I have tested account kit sms verification on my local server and everything went right but when I push the editings on my remote server it starts to return "NOT_AUTHENTICATED" to the page in response.startus.

I have tried to use APP key and secret, that I use normally on remote server, on my local server to test if it was a problem of api version (indeed on my local I use a Facebook APP with 2.5 version and on server I use a Facebook APP with 2.2 version) but everything went right on my local server and I get the right response.status.

When I insert the sms verification code on account kit popup it told me that the number it's verified but when it closes itself I get response.status = NOT_AUTHENTICATED.

Comment: Are you calling against graph.accountkit.com? That's on version 1.0 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi

Comment: Hy @OlgaKuznetsova when I said version 2.2 or 2.5 I mean for version of the master FB APP. Yes I'm calling 1.0 version of account kit (I also tried with 1.1 the latest version but without results). Sorry for the bad explanation :S

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: @Finn87: were you able to solve this? If so, what did you do?

Comment: @Finn87 I forgot to set up the allowed address in the fb application for my production server.